# Java NoClassDefFound Error when trying to run

Tags: java, package

I'm fairly new to working with packages in java but I've got a file structure thats:

- project

  - classes

    - src

      - com

        - main

          - Billing.class
          - Password.class
  - src

    - com

      - main

        - Billing.java
        - Password.java

Each java file has package `package src.com.main;` at the top.
I'm compiling from the project folder using `javac -d ./classes/ ./src/com/main/*.java` and it compiles fine. When I go to run it using `java classes/src/com/main/Billing` is gives me a NoClassDefFound exception. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Entire Error:
`java classes/src/com/main/BillingException in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: classes/src/com/main/Billing (wrong name: src/com/main/Billing)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)`

Comment: Post the whole error

Comment: java -cp classes/ Billing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cd project/classes/
java -cp . src.com.main.Billing
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class files are not in the classpath that may be the case.

If you are using *maven* and *eclipse* try the command **mvn eclipse:eclipse**
or

you can set the classpath using command prompt also where your .class files are located.

For example:

**C:> set CLASSPATH=classpath1;classpath2..**

Comment: I'm not using maven or eclipse. I'm compiling from linux terminal. What would the classpaths be? classes/src/com/main?

Comment: this will help you.. [ http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html ]

Answer (score 0):

i think you use other class in your class that is on other package or jar file if so! you need to define Class Path to enable java find your dependencies.